# No images when I move CSS file to its own folder

Tags: html, css, filepath

I recently tried to organize my code into folders (images,css, js) I put my css and js files into their respective folders. Then I changed the links on the html:

```
<link href="css/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

However, now none of the images are displayed.

How can I make my images re-appear while maintaining the CSS file in it's own CSS folder?

Edit:
I forgot to add some crucial information. Some of the images do actually appear, but some of them don't. It's a stranger error. Everything is linked correctly in the filepath, and named correctly with case sensitivity in mind. But only some of the images load when running the html page.

Comment: Post your stylesheet. Odds are that the paths to any images aren't correct.

Comment: Indeed, when changing the path of your CSS, the path of the images change also. (Try ../ before the image links.)

Answer (score 1):

If the location of those folders is a directory before where the code is then you would need to put '../css/design.css'. You would also need to do this for the images. So if the images are like this for example: 'images/image1.jpg' and now you have moved the folder up one level, you need to put '../images/image1.jpg'.

For Example, the structure:

```
    BEFORE: +---- Main HTML file
            +---- CSS file
            +---- image1.jpg
            +---- image2.jpg
            +---- image3.jpg
            +---- image4.jpg
            \


    AFTER:  +---- Main HTML file
            +--+- CSS folder
            |  \---- design.css
            |
            +--+- Images folder
            |  +---- image1.jpg
            |  +---- image2.jpg
            |  +---- image3.jpg
            |  \---- image4.jpg
            \
```

See after, the directory has changed so you need to add the '../'.

I hope that makes sense and answers the question, and good luck.

Comment: That's exactly how I have the files structured, but this is what I have href="css/design.css" because if I add an extra / like you recommended none of the css works  link href="/css/design.css" this doesn't work

Comment: You need to add '../' two extra dots and a forward slash, to indicate that the folders are a level above. Your comment says you tried to add an extra forward slash only, but you need to add the two dots before it. Hope you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Moving CSS files to any folder does not create any issue as far as you are linking them properly in HTML files. Do check the file name and path you are writing in HTML.

Comment: keep case sensitive property of file and folder name in your mind.

Comment: Yes, the paths are correctly written, though I forgot to mention that some images appear and some don't, but all the images are correctly linked to an image folder

Comment: can you share your code with me so that i can look into it?

Answer (score 0):

troubleshoot this first by changing all of your paths to direct paths. If this works then you are having a problem with the paths. It might be a decent idea to have direct paths anyway as with 404 pages and the likes, you can never be totally sure where the page will be loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. I forgot to go to the css file and add ../ to the embedded url images **url(images/crosshatch.png);** switching it to

> url(../images/crosshatch.png);

Once I added ../ to all the embedded images and save it. Then all the images show on my html.

Hope this answer can help somebody out there.